# Get mysql table checksum using SQL queries

Tags: mysql, database, checksum

Mysql allows to generate and return table checksum for InnoDB and MyISAM table types. But I'm struggling to find a SQL query to read the already available checksum from the database without creating a new checksum. (I don't want to calculate the checksum by my own as the table is really big)

I'm looking for a query like this.

```
select checksum(table_name)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MyISAM:** For MyISAM tables, if you need to determine checksum frequently, you can create the table with `CHECKSUM=1` clause.

Now, all you need to do is use: `CHECKSUM TABLE <table_name> QUICK`

Refer: [MySQL CHECKSUM Table Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/checksum-table.html)

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for